# Typescript Mysterious Intersection

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript3.0

TLDR: [Playground Repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20firstModule%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'firstModule'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mutation%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(opts%3A%20%7Bvariables%3A%20%7BfirstModuleArg%3A%20string%7D%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20secondModule%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'secondModule'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mutation%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(opts%3A%20%7Bvariables%3A%20%7BsecondModuleArg%3A%20number%7D%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AfirstModule.mutation()(%7B%20variables%3A%20%7B%20firstModuleArg%3A%20'test'%20%7D%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AsecondModule.mutation()(%7B%20variables%3A%20%7B%20secondModuleArg%3A%20123%20%7D%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20forms%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20firstModule%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20secondModule%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20getFormConfig%20%3D%20(root%3A%20'firstModule'%20%7C%20'secondModule')%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20rootObj%20%3D%20forms%5Broot%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20rootObj%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20mutation%3A%20firstModuleMutation%20%7D%20%3D%20getFormConfig('firstModule')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AfirstModuleMutation()(%7B%20variables%3A%20%7B%20firstModuleArg%3A%20'1234'%20%7D%20%7D)%3B)

In my application, I'm defining multiple form modules which look roughly like:

```
const firstModule = {
    name: 'firstModule',
    mutation: () => {
        return (opts: {variables: {firstModuleArg: string}}) => {} 
    }
}

const secondModule = {
    name: 'secondModule',
    mutation: () => {
        return (opts: {variables: {secondModuleArg: number}}) => {} 
    }
}
```

As you can see, each mutation function returns a function that expects a particularly shaped `variables` field.

Usage of each module directly works just fine:

```
firstModule.mutation()({ variables: { firstModuleArg: 'test' } }); => ok

secondModule.mutation()({ variables: { secondModuleArg: 123 } }); => ok
```

However, I'm also creating a central registry of these forms so that I can look them up from elsewhere like so:

```
const forms = {
    firstModule,
    secondModule
}


const getFormConfig = (root: 'firstModule' | 'secondModule') => {
    const rootObj = forms[root];

    return rootObj;
}
```

This is where the issue is.. When I then try to refer to a single member of the combined form object, it seems like Typescript is automatically creating an intersection of the `variables` fields and throwing the following error:

```
const { mutation: firstModuleMutation } = getFormConfig('firstModule');

firstModuleMutation()({ variables: { firstModuleArg: '1234' } });
```

[image: Typescript Error]

I imagine I'm missing something fairly simple here, but was hoping to get some insight into how to get the ideal behavior (when I specifically retrieve the `firstModule`, I only want it to validate the variables field from that module). Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Have not tried TypeScript. `firstModule.mutation()` returns a function, correct?

Comment: Yup, it returns a function that is expecting to be called like `firstModule.mutation()({variables: firstModuleArg: 'someString'})`

Comment: The function does not return a value, at `=> {}`, correct? What is the purpose of `opts` at `return (opts: {variables: {secondModuleArg: number}}) => {}`?

Comment: I left out the internal behavior of the mutation functions for simplicity (and not to confuse the issue here). In reality, we use the opts to make a request to the server.

Comment: Then `opts` is not a special TypeScript mechanism, but the expected name of the parameter passed? Not `variables` as the property of the destructured object?

Comment: @Paleo has the right approach -- overloads are preferred in this case. If you _need_ to do it with arrow functions, you have to use generics, but it's way uglier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is defined this way, TypeScript loses the relation between your module name and your mutation return type.

You can either use function overloads or define your function using type parameters. Since the first solution was already provided, let me present the second approach. Its advantage is that it scales indefinitely. If you decide to extend your model, it will just work, whereas with overloads you would have to update them every time your model changes.

We will need a few commonly used helpers first.

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;
```

Your domain model:

```
/**
 * Type aliases.
 */
type Forms = typeof forms;
type Module = ValueOf<Forms>;

/**
 * The return type for `getFormConfig`.
 */
type TransformedModule<T extends Module> = Overwrite<T, { mutation: ReturnType<T['mutation']> }>;
```

The final solution:

```
export function getFormConfig<K extends keyof Forms>(arg: K) {
  const module = forms[arg];

  return ({ ...module, mutation: module.mutation() }) as TransformedModule<Forms[K]>;
}
```

Usage:

```
getFormConfig('firstModule').mutation({ variables: { firstModuleArg: 'foo' } })
getFormConfig('secondModule').mutation({ variables: { secondModuleArg: 42 } });
```

Comment: Good stuff -- although I think return type can be simplified to `Forms[ModuleName] & { mutation: ReturnType<Mutation> }` right? Then we don't need `Overwrite<>`

Comment: Sorry for the potentially simple question...where exactly would I put this declaration? When I add it directly above my function, it says "overload signatures must all be exported" but then adding an `export` raises "Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient."

Comment: @ChristianSantos Not exactly — if you merge them, the definition for `mutation` will be an intersection of the existing mutation and the return type of one. This means `getFormConfig('firstModule').mutation()({ variables: { firstModuleArg: '' }})` would be be correct on the type level, but fail in runtime (notice the extra function call).

Comment: @NaderHendawi Nevermind the declaration. I have updated my answer with a proper function body (as opposed to just its declaration).

Answer (score 1):

You could help the compiler with overloads:

```
function getFormConfig(root: 'firstModule'):
    typeof firstModule & { mutation: ReturnType<typeof firstModule.mutation> }
function getFormConfig(root: 'secondModule'):
    typeof secondModule & { mutation: ReturnType<typeof secondModule.mutation> }
function getFormConfig(root: 'firstModule' | 'secondModule') {
    const rootObj = forms[root];

    const mutation = rootObj.mutation();
    return {...rootObj, mutation}
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much Paleo and @Christian Santos.  Out of curiosity, is there a more idiomatic way to specify an overload for any values that get passed in? My repro case above only has two modules, but we'll most likely have ~15 in practice. Would be great to not have to manually add an overload for each

Comment: it'd be something like `type Forms = typeof forms; type FormsKeys = keyof Forms;` and `getFormConfig2 = <T extends FormsKeys>(root: T): Forms[T] & { mutation: ReturnType<Forms[T]['mutation']> } => { ... }`