# TypeScript unexpected intersection

Tags: typescript

I have a registry of "models" and when I select a model from the registry, and call a method on it, TypeScript expects an intersection of the parameters across all registered models.

For brevity, I've reproduced this bug with a dummy method "getName".

```ts
export class Model<N extends string> {
  public name: N;

  constructor(name: N) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public getName = (options: { __type: N }) => options.__type;
}

export const Book = new Model("Book");
export const User = new Model("User");

export const modelRegistry = { Book, User };

export type ModelRegistry = typeof modelRegistry;

export const makeModel = <N extends keyof ModelRegistry>(name: N) => (
  options: Parameters<ModelRegistry[N]["getName"]>[0],
) => {
  const model = modelRegistry[name];
  return model.getName(options); // <-- bug: TS expects this to be { __type: User } & { __type: Book }
};
```

[image]

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Model%3CN%20extends%20string%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20name%3A%20N%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(name%3A%20N)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20getName%20%3D%20(options%3A%20%7B%20__type%3A%20N%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20options.__type%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20Book%20%3D%20new%20Model(%22Book%22)%3B%0D%0Aexport%20const%20User%20%3D%20new%20Model(%22User%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20modelRegistry%20%3D%20%7B%20Book%2C%20User%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ModelRegistry%20%3D%20typeof%20modelRegistry%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20makeModel%20%3D%20%3CN%20extends%20keyof%20ModelRegistry%3E(name%3A%20N)%20%3D%3E%20(%0D%0A%20%20options%3A%20Parameters%3CModelRegistry%5BN%5D%5B%22getName%22%5D%3E%5B0%5D%2C%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20model%20%3D%20modelRegistry%5Bname%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20model.getName(options)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20bug%3A%20TS%20expects%20this%20to%20be%20%7B%20__type%3A%20User%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20__type%3A%20Book%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: I looked at this question for a potential answer, however I was unable to get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714232/typescript-mysterious-intersection

Comment: How is `makeModel` supposed to be called?

Comment: `makeModel` is really just an artifact of my real code, you can ignore its naming. In practice, I have external data streaming in, and I transform that data based on the `__type` property. I fetch data from an endpoint, convert it to a schema (using `io-ts`), and then convert it to a "model" (it gains certain methods depending on `__type`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler doesn't know how to interpret the generic `ModelRegistry[N]["getName"]` as correlated to the type `N` when you try to call it, and instead widens `N` to the full union type `keyof ModelRegistry`.  Therefore it sees `model.getName` as a union of function types of different parameter types.  Before TypeScript 3.3 such a union was just not callable at all (see [microsoft/TypeScript#7294](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294)).  In TypeScript 3.3 support was added to allow such functions to be [called with an intersection of the parameters for each function in the union](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  That's better than "not callable", but it still leaves a lot to be desired, especially in the case you have here where there are *correlated union types* involved (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)).

In cases like these the easiest way to address it is to accept that you are smarter than the compiler and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) the types you expect to see.  To demonstrate I'll just use `as any` to silence the compiler:

```
export const makeModel = <N extends keyof ModelRegistry>(name: N) => (
  options: Parameters<ModelRegistry[N]["getName"]>[0],
): ReturnType<ModelRegistry[N]["getName"]> => {
  const model = modelRegistry[name];
  return model.getName(options as any) as any; // I'm smarter than the compiler 
};
```

This should work for you... you could tighten the `any` assertions up to more applicable types, if you desire.  Note that I've manually annotated the return type of the curried `makeModel` call to be `ReturnType<ModelRegistry[N]["getName"]`, since the compiler is unlikely to be able to figure that out.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Really appreciate the insight, and links to the TypeScript documentation and GitHub issues for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around this error is to define generic version of `makeModel` which can work on arbitrary registry, then define specific version for one instance of registry:

```
export const makeAnyModel = <Registry extends { [N in string]: Model<N> }>
(registry: Registry, name: keyof Registry) => (
  options: Parameters<Registry[keyof Registry]["getName"]>[0],
) => {
    const model = registry[name];
    return model.getName(options);
};

export const makeModel = <N extends keyof ModelRegistry>(name: N) => 
    makeAnyModel(modelRegistry, name);
```

There are no errors in `makeAnyModel` because `N` is assumed to be `string` when typechecking the implementation - inferred type for `getName` is

```
Model<string>.getName: (options: { __type: string; }) => string
```