# Factory creating a wrapped object based on input object

Tags: typescript, factory-pattern

I try to create a factory, that would return a wrapped object based on the input object. Return type should be dependent on the input. I kind of got it, but with a horrible type assertions in the factory method, because it seems to be impossible to implement the interface I defined.

There are finite types of `Data` available for an input, and finite types of `Wrappers` that can be used for wrapping the result. There are also finite classes of objects that can be wrapped.

Is there any possible way of implementing it in a way that would not require removing type-checking (`as any`) in the factory's implementation?

And one more question that would help me a lot with understanding what's going on here exactly:

Without removing type checking there is this error:

```
Type 'DefaultSingleWrapped<T["class"]>' is not assignable to type 'WrappersMap<T["class"]>[T["type"]]'.
  Type 'DefaultSingleWrapped<T["class"]>' is not assignable to type 'SingleWrapped<T["class"]> & ArrayWrapped<T["class"]>'.
    Type 'DefaultSingleWrapped<T["class"]>' is not assignable to type 'ArrayWrapped<T["class"]>'.
      The types returned by 'getValue()' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'T["class"]' is not assignable to type 'T["class"][]'.(2322)
```

From where this `SingleWrapped<T["class"]> & ArrayWrapped<T["class"]>` intersection comes from? It's somehow inferred but I'm not sure what's the logic behind it.

```
enum DataTypes {
  DATA_TYPE1 = 'datatype1',
  DATA_TYPE2 = 'datatype2',
}

class Class1 {
  property1: boolean = true;
}

class Class2 {
  property2: boolean = false;
}

interface ServiceObjectMap {
  'class1': Class1,
  'class2': Class2,
}

type ClassUnion = ServiceObjectMap[keyof ServiceObjectMap];

interface Data<T = ClassUnion> {
  type: DataTypes,
  class: T,
}

interface DataOne<T extends ServiceObjectMap[keyof ServiceObjectMap]> extends Data<T> {
  type: DataTypes.DATA_TYPE1,
}

interface DataTwo<T extends ServiceObjectMap[keyof ServiceObjectMap]> extends Data<T> {
  type: DataTypes.DATA_TYPE2,
}

interface SingleWrapped<T> {
  getValue(): T,
}

interface ArrayWrapped<T> {
  getValue(): T[],
}

interface WrappersMap<T> {
  [DataTypes.DATA_TYPE1]: SingleWrapped<T>,
  [DataTypes.DATA_TYPE2]: ArrayWrapped<T>,
}

class DefaultSingleWrapped<T> implements SingleWrapped<T> {

  constructor(private obj: T) {}

  getValue(): T {
    return this.obj;
  }
}

interface Factory {
  createWrappedObjectFromData<T extends Data>(data: T): WrappersMap<T['class']>[T['type']];
}

class DefaultSingleWrappedFactory implements Factory {
  createWrappedObjectFromData<T extends Data<T['class']>>(data: T): WrappersMap<T['class']>[T['type']] {
    return new DefaultSingleWrapped<T['class']>(new ((data['class'] as any)['constructor'])({zz: 'bleble'})) as any;
  }
}

const factory1: Factory = new DefaultSingleWrappedFactory();
const data1: DataOne<Class1> = {
  type: DataTypes.DATA_TYPE1,
  class: Class1['prototype'],
};

const i = factory1.createWrappedObjectFromData(data1);
const value = i.getValue();
console.log(value.property1);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=77&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdgGcoG8CwAUFLAILKkD6yAmgAoCiAjFALxQDkAJoohsEw4AaIiRjkqtRgCY2nHkgT9pwogF8iRAMYAbOFhwBhPQZYFiUdACcA9pitKmALigAjGzZ3A4IOQitgwADc6pqEuvpGJliy5iTWdsAOqNIu7p7evuwAZnA6WMGhhEQAliAISblawFAAykkAbiXVAPKuAFbAWggAsnDoeKKcEaYcLsaRTCIWHCMxY1ATBtLTGsWESpiL0QCqICU2WXWNzcBtnd196ADaANbAqDbZx1ZNrR1dvf0AuiHrZRUrFUavAkAAeZByJZYPYHEAAPkGFk2wBcoJQ-Cw0xIcxcyFWYQBlTg1VgvBaIGAEKgwAAHhUQFwcPVXqdzp8rncHk8Xm8zh9Lj9EXSGUyyeDkIi4lAUWjeGhMFgAHTiCjUejMAn-crE0no5AAdxs1JFoDFLL57MFN3uj2eFrZAq+6G+wvpZpw6IhUqGsvFGMVKok6pkWtKOqBJJqtTKAHMvAB1Kz9TBcb1Ikix4AIABqeUCAAoAJR4sOEImR0mkKzJ1BJlPANOSjNQLO5-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-FtO0KYd6IUlS0JMIi7DSn6U6BnuIaamB0TjNETCaQk3GGb26h-No-VQCUch7TxTBKvx3j+clXDCUFIVIM1SBMEWj2I0heE1OwJRKjhHYPQj20ZEqOg2LGBYU4ESoJPYjik2ERBAA)

Answer (score 1):

There are two `as any`, each of them represent a type problem.

The first one is that the interpreter do not know that `data['class']['constructor']` is a constructor. In case to solve it, we can create a `Constructor` type to replace `['constructor']` and `['prototype']`.

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

interface Data<T = ClassUnion> {
    type: DataTypes,
    class: Constructor<T>,
}

createWrappedObjectFromData(data) {
    return new DefaultSingleWrapped(new data.class({zz: 'bleble'}));
}
```

The second one is that [typescript cannot interpret WrappersMap<T['class']>[T['type']] correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933800/typescript-unexpected-intersection).

As you stated that your types are known and limited, I would suggest you to use function overloading.

```
abstract class Wrapped {
    abstract getValue(): any
}

interface SingleWrapped<T> extends Wrapped {
    getValue(): T,
}

interface ArrayWrapped<T> extends Wrapped {
    getValue(): T[],
}

interface Factory {
    createWrappedObjectFromData<T extends ClassUnion>(data: Data<T>): Wrapped;
}

class DefaultSingleWrappedFactory implements Factory {
    createWrappedObjectFromData<T extends ClassUnion>(data: DataOne<T>): SingleWrapped<T>
    createWrappedObjectFromData<T extends ClassUnion>(data: DataTwo<T>): ArrayWrapped<T>
    createWrappedObjectFromData<T extends ClassUnion>(data: Data<T>): Wrapped {
        return new DefaultSingleWrapped(new data.class({zz: "bleble"}));
    }
}
```

Here is a modified version of the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-qIcFcIKscoQUDmUAA6nX0JguE6SNXa-WoNjgAgAGp5QIo4n4kCoIqlGU0uU1WplbFeVv9Dv5qA2qM4Nft4CdzkD4ej4DjlzISuEQPz+WkKx11B7jeO7c5lttjtd-uDkc6McTlAyBEleN60h+65JFgVybpy1zFu6pbelIzDfC4S4gCuwDPge+aClA8G8GgiFepIvrSGhUD3o+OFcHhM7hNEsDALkYA6AgGFYbRm4lBA6BeBAoAINqy6rp+uGOuYQxaKKATiii1glA0iA1DYHQXqSnJrEMx5-gBF7fiQViDmAVi+AgAAWJQemp7R-CQazadec7gQAYvWEKoN+WjGSptFxggrm2BAebIFu2Z2syrKHDCKIKHAPK8PmgG0X8TlNjALFwGxHGidh4lcO54pebx-HAIJ5Q4EVCCed5vkVP5aZBTYIVJWFb6Rbs+wxXFvCJUgSrAMl6F5dxsLSfV+WQVwAXNa1DrhbaUSRNF7K9Ug-UoGGw1UQ+cBPgV+YTd4DUFbNwWhYtO7bCt3VrfFm07bRhlQMZCCmb4CLIplrHsZxYnTSiX1QPFaJzCiuBQAAXlDLgcK4XgI8AHBQGoxLEvZqMMTJIAglAVQ1VYqDOFA1W1ewwM-dlf2jQVZNE+Ofw43j8Uk7yg2QsyTBwuwnJFkRJakeWfrSdE4zRFM6h-NoopQCUcgE55TBg5NjUXIFF28OtcBMBjMu4w2yn-jU7AlGiumnoz+tYBkaI6DY2IokbgRogk9iOHr6xEEAA).

Comment: Thanks! Although in meantime I think I found out the way of achieving this without overloading – by using correlated union types, that are available only in the nightly builds of TS for now (will land in 4.6.0). I will probably post it as second answer soon.