# Optionally wrapped objects created by a factory cannot be assigned generically to a map of such objects

Tags: typescript, factory, typescript-generics, factory-pattern

So, I have this pretty complex case I try to solve. Basically, I have these Bags of values of different types. I try to implement a factory, that takes a `Definition` as an input, then produces a value that can be wrapped, depending on the definition given. It almost works. Almost, because the only case, where it doesn't work is when I try to make a generic assignment of values to the map, at the very end.

Is it some kind of a limitation of TypeScript? Can it be solved without using assertions?

I already tried to solve this issue some time ago, and even posted a similar question: [Factory creating a wrapped object based on input object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70495308/factory-creating-a-wrapped-object-based-on-input-object) , however, this is a different implementation, and a different error. It feels like it should work.

```
enum BagTypes {
  'test1' = 'test1',
  'test2' = 'test2',
  'test3' = 'test3',
};

interface Bags {
  'bag1': {
    'type': BagTypes.test1,
    'value': 123,
  },
  'bag2': {
    'type': BagTypes.test3,
    'value': 'some string',
  },
}

type BagTypeMap = {
  [K in keyof Bags]: Bags[K]['type'];
}

type BagValueMap = {
  [K in keyof Bags]: Bags[K]['value'];
}

type Wrapper<T extends unknown> = {
  getValue(): T;
};

type PossiblyWrappedValueMap<T extends BagValueMap[keyof BagValueMap]> = {
  [BagTypes.test1]: T,
  [BagTypes.test2]: T,
  [BagTypes.test3]: Wrapper<T>,
}

interface Definition<T extends keyof Bags> {
  type: Bags[T]['type'];
  value: Bags[T]['value'],
}

interface Factory {
  createPossiblyWrappedValue: <T extends Definition<keyof Bags>>(definition: T) => PossiblyWrappedValueMap<T['value']>[T['type']];
}

declare const factory: Factory;

declare const possiblyWrappedValueMap: Partial<{
  [K in keyof Bags]: PossiblyWrappedValueMap<BagValueMap[K]>[BagTypeMap[K]];
}>;

function setValueOnSomeMap<T extends keyof Bags>(id: T, definition1: Definition<'bag1'>, definition2: Definition<'bag2'>, definition3: Definition<T>) {
  // These concrete assigments work as expected.
  possiblyWrappedValueMap['bag1'] = factory.createPossiblyWrappedValue<Definition<'bag1'>>(definition1);
  possiblyWrappedValueMap['bag2'] = factory.createPossiblyWrappedValue<Definition<'bag2'>>(definition2);

  // Why this generic assignement doesn't work? Is there any way to make it work without assertions?
  const possiblyWrappedValue = factory.createPossiblyWrappedValue<Definition<T>>(definition3);
  possiblyWrappedValueMap[id] = possiblyWrappedValue;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAQghgcwCoE8AOwDOUDeBYAKCigHIAXLMgRhKgF5SLNqSAaQ48ygJloa+a92RRpQDMfUcwnCAvgG5ChAJYgKAJwBmcAMbBYibPhEkARohoAuXB2KN0wEtfjIHmAHRNqwu6QBucAA2YI7WVNxiPlCyUWaIvNbGvuQOTgauGB5ekbacAcGhpJgA9hD6zOqqCGy2MYSySgRkDumoGACycGj0NiIA2gDSUKpQANbAKMWa6ZgAus6Gg7N9KRgks4oEDQSEzRjpAGpBIZ3dDElQg8MgYxNTM-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-FAACS2DzdmTkgKWSJwHNxRQBAcDjMMO3Hd5SKulZxRgDtzk0eoSmYKdtjfr+SGdah4rxYWiWtVWNYw4BcP8r1hmSUgQ3FepYjjSIlUZV1tWCjxsw9CTsM1eKHxAA)

Comment: Ugh, this looks like two layers of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the approach in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) is not working for me.  Even if it *did* work it would require so much refactoring that it would probably not be worth it.  I'd say just use a type assertion and move on.  I'd write up an answer but I'm exhausted from banging at this 

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I'm fighting this exact issue on and off for many months now, for my personal project. I've tried multiple implementations that feel soooo close to working, like this one, but there is always just one layer of indirection too much. Essentially what I need is being able to produce values of type read from a type map, that can be wrapped in whatever from another type map, and being able to assign them to a map... If there is any other way of getting this to work, I would almost kill for being able to learn it lol. But I guess I just need to accept assertion in some place. Eh.

Comment: @jcalz Just an idea, but maybe there could be implemented some kind of a "type converter" that would contain assertion, that would solve this specific problem? (the point of it would be that by using assertion it would convert types that *we* know that are compatible, even if TS doesn't) That way this type assertion would be kind of isolated. I would accept such thing as an answer, and I'll think about it myself when I'll be able to.

Comment: @jcalz One more idea just occured to me. What if factory would return... an intersection of two compatible types, that TS cannot map to each other? I will experiment with this, but I feel it might be an actual answer.